# ApostropheCMS: How do I let users show/hide the image title?

Tags: image, widget, apostrophe-cms

I want to give users a choice to show/hide the  image title that's in `apostrophe-images-widgets/views/widgetBase.html`

So, I created project-level copy of `apostrophe-images` module, and added the `showTitle` boolean field in addFields like so:

`{
        type: 'boolean',
        name: 'showTitle',
        label: 'Show Title'
      },`

Also in project-level, under `apostrophe-images-widgets/views/widget.html` I overrode the original widget template with this:

`{%- block title -%}{% if data.widget.showTitle %}<h4>{{ image.title }}</h4>{% endif %}{%- endblock -%}`

**But this does not work**... I guess because I'm setting the showTitle option in `apostrophe-images`, but trying to use that option in `apostrophe-images-widget`. What would be the correct way to implement this?

**By the way**, setting the option manually and then using `data.option.showTitle` does work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, anwering my own question here. I found that I should use `image.showTitle` rather than `data.widget.showTitle`